# Activate app whenever the screen is unlocked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I  create an app,  which simply take user password input to exit from that app. But I want it to activate automatically every-time screen is unlocked. Please suggest me how can I do it.

Comment: Have you tried search for it on Google?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) to determine when app is resumed after being hidden. Simply add this method to your activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
    // activate your thing
}
```

**Note** this method will run every time your app is resumed, meaning when it is created, reopened after having it lingering in the background, and when the screen is unlocked as well (assuming your app is opened after the screen is unlocked). The screen has to be locked for a few seconds before this method will run as well.

I might suggest instead to use `onRestart()`, because this is basically the same thing except that it won't run when the app is created:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    // Called after the activity has been stopped, 
    // just prior to it being started again.
    // Always followed by onStart()

    // activate your thing
}
```